# how to get rid of “Untrusted Connection” error, with my own certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have developed a web application and used my certificate for SSL. I didn't buy the CA certificates. So the client will get the Untrusted Connection error every time. do you have any idea how we can get rid of this error in each browser? I tried to add my generated certificate to the browser but it didn't work and it didn't recognize my certificate type.

thanks,

-- Mana

Answer (score 0):

Every user's browser has be able to verify the certificate chain, ending with a root certificate authority (CA) that they trust.  Typically that means each user importing the root cert for your CA into their browsers as a trusted certificate.

All browsers accept PEM-encoded certificates.  If you export your root cert in PEM form, all browsers should be willing to import it.

If your users are working on a shared host, then you can import the root cert into the host's shared trusted certificate database, instead of making each user import the certificate separately.  In Linux the shared database is in /etc/ssl/certs, and you can update it with update-ca-certificates(1).